# How Can I remove or hide the export page in WordPress menu?

Tags: admin-menu, sub-menu

I'm trying to remove the export.php page from WordPress admin menu -> tools
 for a multisite so only the network admin could see it

I have the following code so far but can't get it to work.

```
//***************************************************
// Remove export Page
//***************************************************
function remove_menu_export_pages() {
    remove_menu_page('export.php'); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_menu_export_pages' );
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever in doubt about a WordPress function, consult the Codex: [Function_Reference/remove_menu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page).

The correct function is [`remove_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/remove_submenu_page) hooked into `admin_menu`.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_submenu_wpse_82873' );

function remove_submenu_wpse_82873() 
{
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    // If user not Super Admin remove export page
    if ( !is_super_admin() ) 
    {
        remove_submenu_page( 'tools.php', 'export.php' );
    }
}
```

And then you'd probably would like to also block the direct access to that page through the URL address (`http://example.com/wp-admin/export.php`):

```
add_action( 'admin_head-export.php', 'prevent_url_access_wpse_82873' );

function prevent_url_access_wpse_82873()
{
    global $current_user;

    // Only Super Admin Authorized, exit if user not
    if ( !is_super_admin() ) {

      // User not authorized to access page, redirect to dashboard
      wp_redirect( admin_url( 'index.php' ) ); 
      exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it works great however the export page is not available to supper admin

Comment: @Oudin, is it working with your edit?

Comment: yes it does tested it works

Answer (score 0):

the simple working code is here:

```
add_filter( 'bp_settings_show_user_data_page', 'logan_plz_remove_export_data_tab_from_myprofile' );
function logan_plz_remove_export_data_tab_from_myprofile($filter) {
    return false;
}
```

please write this code in your **functions.php.**

refer: http://prntscr.com/ojcxut