# Hide Jetpack for Contributor

Tags: plugin-jetpack

I installed [jetpack](http://jetpack.me) to my wordpress blog site. How can I hide `jetpack` to contributors, and show it only to administrators?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code will do the trick. Create a file, `jetpack-hide.php` (or another name of your choosing) and upload it to `wp-content/mu-plugins` (create that directory if it doesn't exist).

```
add_action( 'jetpack_admin_menu', 'hide_jetpack_from_others' );
function hide_jetpack_from_others() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        remove_menu_page( 'jetpack' );
    }
}
```

To re-enable JetPack for all users, simply delete that file, or rename it. I usually append `.OFF` to a `mu-plugin` that I want to disable, e.g., `jetpack-hide.php.OFF`.

Comment: +1 for the Jetpack specific hook. Using `current_user_can` with a role is a bit controversial... better use a capability. [Redirecting](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82876/12615) URL access attempts is a nice touch too ;)

Comment: Thanks, @brasofilo. Wish I could take credit, it was adapted from [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/shock-a-subscriber-can-admin-the-jetpack-options?replies=8).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **custom plugin**, that hide this item in the menu, if the current user have the role "contributor".

The jetpack plugin allow the menu item for all roles, there have the capability `read`, on a default install have this all roles.
`add_menu_page( 'Jetpack', $title, 'read', 'jetpack', array( $this, 'admin_page' ), 'div' )`

A example for a custom plugin, there remove this menu item, if the user have not the role `administrator`.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Remove Jetpack Menu Item for roles smaller Admin
 */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'fb_remove_menu_entries' );
function fb_remove_menu_entries () {
    // with WP 3.1 and higher
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )
        remove_menu_page( 'jetpack' );

}
```

More background about this topic do you find as example in [this post](http://wpengineer.com/2233/remove-menu-item-in-wordpress-admin-panel/).

**Alternative** is a **plugin**, that give you a options for this, like [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/). This plugin allow to hide different areas, objekt for different roles. A little bid easier to go to your goal, but more options as custom plugin.

Comment: Um, your code is nearly identical to what I posted, with the exception that your function will run even if JetPack is not currently installed.

Comment: Your code is one point better, you use a custom hook from the plugin. If the plugin Jetpack is not active, then is not a error. The core funtion check it and is not a problem.